# Why xray-indexer goes down every time whenever start xray?

Tags: devops, artifactory, jfrog-xray, jfrog-mission-control

I am not able to start xray-indexer. Whenever i try to run xray service, it starts for few seconds then it goes down.

> /opt/jfrog/xray/scripts/xray.sh start

Output :

> /opt/jfrog/xray/scripts/xray.sh status

```
Checking Xray services...
Checking xray-server...                           Running, the PID is 206755
Checking xray-indexer...                          The process appears to be dead but pidfile still exists
Checking xray-persist...                          Running, the PID is 206961
Checking xray-analysis...                         Running, the PID is 207059
```

i also tried running xray-indexer after removing that dead pidfile as shown in error but issue persists.

I am using following version of artifactory and xray,

Jfrog Xray version : Xray 2.11.4

Jfrog Artifactory version : 6.15.0 rev 61500900

Comment: Do you have anything in the logs?